# Is there a tool to find words that are related to multiple input words?

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for a similar tool to thesaurus.com, but one where you can enter multiple words. For example, I'm looking for a word that describes something between `match` and `race`. Or one that captures (or relates most to) `family`, `company` and `sports club`.

Comment: You can look up the individual words in a dictionary or thesaurus and look for matches (general sense). How appropriate these are will vary; there may be no suitable words 'half way between' or embodying the senses of two separate words, never mind three or more.

Comment: You hafta lay out the path before you can say what's "halfway between". Lexical semantics is not organized like an ordered field; there are millions of possible dimensions and no necessary ordering, so mostly there isn't a single word for any given concept you can think of. That's why there are phrases and sentences.

Comment: A traditional (dead tree) thesaurus is arranged conceptually rather than, say, alphabetically; it's not just a dictionary of synonyms. A good old *Roget's* (not the pocket edition, which is alphabetical, or the electronic version, which just automates synonym lookup) ought to get you where you want to go.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a request for resources.

Comment: This is NOT opinion-based. It's clear cut whether something finds related words. It isn't asking for people to debate which the "best" one is.

Comment: FYI as probably well-known at the moment, nowadays I use Chat GTP for finding related words

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the [reverse dictionary feature](http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml) of [OneLook.com.](http://www.onelook.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find an easily accessible live online demo of this, but if you're technically inclined, you could adapt a [Jupyter Notebook of automated wordsmithing](https://github.com/danielfrg/word2vec/blob/main/examples/word2vec.ipynb) to:

1. Convert some words to vectors
2. Average the vectors with varying weights to your taste
3. Find closest other vectors to those averages
4. Find the words corresponding to those vectors.

To look up words closest to a vector instead of a word use the method [`model.closest`](https://github.com/danielfrg/word2vec/blob/b8a84f5174ed6cdddeb3884579bd8e322f041494/word2vec/wordvectors.py#L108) instead of `model.similar`.